# Python type() function issue, str not callable

Tags: python, string, validation, typeerror

I am working on validating a certain piece of data, in this case the strin g 'five' should fail a certain piece of validation because it needs to be 5 (an int)

```
print ">>>>", value
bad_type = type(value).__name__
raise TypeError("expected numeric type for {0} but got '{1}'".format(column,bad_type))
```

prints:

```
.>>>> five
...
bad_type = type(value).__name__
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

However I can do this from the command line:

```
python -c "print type('five').__name__"
```

prints

```
str
```

what am I doing wrong here?  I want to print the type of the value that was passed and failed my custom validation.

Comment: `'five'` is a string, so is `'5'`.

Comment: looks like you defined a variable name `type` somewhere.

Comment: A bit off-topic, if you are looking for a python data validation library then you could take a look at [voluptuous](https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous), which is small, has a well designed interface and is easily extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't over-ridden `type` somewhere?

Also, that's not the Pythonic way for type checking - instead use:

```
try:
    my_int = int(value)
except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    # raise something
```

Comment: yep, that did it.  thanks for the heads up, ill use the pythonic way.  btw, what would be the corresponding way I would check if value is an str?

Comment: @DavidWilliams `if isinstance(some_var, str)` in Py3.x, or normally best to use `if isinstance(some_var, basestring)` in Py2.x, so it covers unicode and str